# How to run C/C++ code using integrated terminal in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

How to launch a C/C++ console application using the integrated terminal in Visual Studio instead of launching a separate terminal window?

#### To clarify more:

When I press the run button right now, this is what happens:

[image]

But what I want is something like this (but it must happen when I press the run button), **where the output is directed to a terminal inside the visual studio window, without launching a separate window**, this will make it easier when debugging because I won't have to switch between multiple windows:
[image]

Comment: Sure you're talking about visual studio, not visual studio code?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code. I want my console C app to be run inside a terminal inside visual studio app, not launching a separate terminal window

Comment: Can't you just run it in the integrated terminal like how you would run it in a separate terminal? Or do you want to click ***run***, and let it automatically run in the integrated terminal?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I don't get what you mean? When I press the run button, a separate terminal window is launched and the output of `printf` for example appears there, but what I want is the results to appear in the integrated terminal inside visual studio, in some tab beside the `output` tab. I searched in settings but couldn't find an option to do that

Comment: You can always manually build the project, and in the terminal go to the directory of your built program, and run the program by typing its name

Comment: That's not how it works, you can do debug, if you want text output in the debug part of visual studio use [outputdebugstring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringw). But your console will always launch.

Comment: Pretty sure visual studio doesn't even have an integrated terminal

Comment: @AlanBirtles It's been added awhile ago: [A more integrated terminal experience](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/a-more-integrated-terminal-experience/)

Comment: @Ranoiaetep you are right, but that is not what the question is about, I updated it to clarify that I want the behaviour you talked about to happen automatically when I press run, without launching a separate window

Comment: There are ways to make a C# application log into a visual studio terminal but not a C++ executable.

Comment: Visual Studio does not currently support launching debugger in the terminal. You could [request a feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp/suggest) and post the link here.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT I opened one [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Support-to-attach-the-debugger-to-the-te/10191933)

Comment: @HII, I'm wondering what's your thoughts about using QtCreator? I think it has exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4):

There is a handy [VsConsoleOutput extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NesviatypaskhaOleksii.VsConsoleOutput) for Visual Studio 2019 / 2022 that redirects program output into Output window inside of Visual Studio.
[image]
However when installing it i've got an exception complaining about incorrect value of `InstalledByMsi` value somewhere in manifest. The workaround is to manually open downloaded .vsix package (which seems to be a .zip archive) using WinRAR or something, adjust one line in `extension.vsixmanifest` file and save updated archive.

```
<Installation AllUsers="true" InstalledByMsi="false">
```

Comment: it seems to direct the output to the `output` tab, good, , one more question, does it prevent the launch of the separate window? The real solution to my problem would be a way to direct the output and input as well to a terminal within the same window as visual studio's window, just like what happens in VSCode for example

Comment: @Haidar It does not prevent the  launch of the separate window, it still pops in the background. And it does not seem to handle input at all.

Comment: Apologies - removed comment.

Comment: For VS 2022 Version 17.7.6 it pops up external console with `Console redirected to Output Window in Visual Studio...` but unfortunately, nothing comes to Output Tab